# Expressão regular para validar string e int em php

Tags: php, regex

Preciso validar essa string.

`$scop = "ES-1236";` chave de acesso valor fixo `ES-` dinamico `1236` sendo o dinamico apenas números inteiros.

para validar estou criando uma variavel com a busca
`$lets = "ES-";`

e a expressão para validar

```
if(preg_match("/{$lets}/i", $let)) {
echo true;
}
```

porém nesse formato ele está aceitando se passar somente `ES-` mas gostaria que ele obrigasse a ter um número inteiro após o `ES-`

Comment: Para fins de conhecimento. Como o ES- não é dinâmico, você também poderia utilizar https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtok.php e testar se o resultado é um número

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá

Você precisa de uma ER que contenha a parte estática e a variável:

No seu caso 'ES-' é a parte estática e os dígitos são variáveis.
Como você precisa de um número inteiro após o '-', então use o '\d' para identificar símbolos numéricos (0,1,2, ...,8,9) e o modificador '+' para que pelo menos um desses apareça.

```php
$scop = "ES-1236";
if(preg_match("/ES-\d+/", $scop)){
    echo "valido";
}else{
    echo "invalido";
}
```

Você pode executar esse código [aqui](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7a09c34795266296674a507ef09b5208bcf18c70):

[Aqui](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/zhF) você tem um testador dessa ER, com algumas strings válidas e inválidas.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(preg_match('/^(ES)-(\d){4}$/', $let))
```

Isso obriga, alem de inciar com ES, ser seguido de - e terminar em 4 digitos